# 50 factorial in Java Using BigInteger

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

So I've been trying to get big factorials like 50 using BigInteger. But when i run this program in cmd, i get unexpected error at line 16: fact=fact.multiply(new BigInteger(getFactorial(n-1))).
I am not even able to see the thrown exception as it gets scrolled out. Please help me find the error.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
class FactorialUsingRecursion {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int num=50;
    String fact=getFactorial(num);
    System.out.println(num+"! = "+fact);
}

static String getFactorial(int n) {
    BigInteger fact=new BigInteger(n+"");

    if(fact.toString()=="1") {
        return "1";
    }
    fact=fact.multiply(new BigInteger(getFactorial(n-1)));//error line
    return fact.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using Strings to multiply 2 numbers?

Comment: Don't compare Strings with `==`

Comment: Big factorials like 50 cannot be contained in primitive data types like even long. U can see the recursive call in the multiplication

Comment: You are comparing string incorrectly which is why it is likely to be running out of memory, however you shouldn't be using string in the first place.

Comment: Why isn't `getFactorial()` returning a `BigInteger` instead of a String?

Comment: because BigInteger takes String as its argument

Comment: Why not compare to [`BigInteger.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE)? e.g. `fact.equals(BigInteger.ONE)`.

Comment: I used BigInteger first time..kind of new to java...so i m not aware of all its functionalities

Comment: I got my solution however in the answer below..i was incorrectly comparing strings as per Lawrey, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with String comparison in if condition. Change that if condition to the following:

```
if(fact.intValue() == 1) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now